# Join rows in MySQL with similar values

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat

I have a MySQL table with Users with budget:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+
| req_id | name      | id_2     | budget   |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+
| 1      | User1     | 9        | 10       |
| 1      | User2     | 9        | 100      |
| 1      | User3     | 9        | 1000     |
| 1      | User4     | 9        | 10000    |
| 2      | User1     | 4        | 5        |
| 2      | User2     | 4        | 50       |
| 2      | User3     | 4        | 500      |
| 2      | User4     | 4        | 5000     |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

The kind of view I want:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| req_id | id_2      | User1    | User2    | User3    | User4    |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1      | 9         | 10       | 100      | 1000     | 10000    |
| 1      | 4         | 5        | 50       | 500      | 5000     |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

The query I used:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
    'IF(`name` = ''', `name`, ''',budget,0) AS ', `name`)
    ) INTO @sql
    FROM myTable;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT req_id, id_2',
                @sql, 
                ' FROM myTable 
              group by req_id, id_2, name 
              order by req_id, id_2, name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This is what i have achieved so far:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| req_id | id_2      | User1    | User2    | User3    | User4    |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1      | 9         | 10       | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| 1      | 9         | 0        | 100      | 0        | 0        |
| 1      | 9         | 0        | 0        | 1000     | 0        |
| 1      | 9         | 0        | 0        | 0        | 10000    |
| 1      | 4         | 5        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| 1      | 4         | 0        | 50       | 0        | 0        |
| 1      | 4         | 0        | 0        | 500      | 0        |
| 1      | 4         | 0        | 0        | 0        | 5000     |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

So my question is, how do I get to join answers in the same row with different values?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Better share an **sql fiddle**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
    'MAX(IF(`name` = ''', `name`, ''',budget,0)) AS ', `name`)
    ) INTO @sql
    FROM myTable;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT req_id, id_2,',
                @sql, 
                ' FROM myTable 
              group by req_id
              order by req_id, id_2, name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**Changes:**

```
1) MAX(IF(`name` = ''', `name`, ''',budget,0)) AS ', `name`)

2) You needed to group by `req_id` only.
```

See a <kbd>[***WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26554/1/5)</kbd>

<sub>*You need to scroll down to see the output</sub>